# Why are locality levels all ANY in a Spark wordcount application running on HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I ran a Spark cluster of 12 nodes (8G memory and 8 cores for each) for some tests.

I'm trying to figure out why data localities of a simple wordcount app in "map" stage are all "Any". The 14GB dataset is stored in HDFS.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried configuring [`spark.locality.wait`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26994025/whats-the-meaning-of-locality-levelon-spark-cluster)?

Comment: Well, since the default value is 3s, you might want to set it higher than that.

Comment: I tried, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same problem and in my case it was a problem with the configuration. I was running on the EC2 and I had a name mismatch. Maybe the same thing happened to you.

When you check how HDFS sees you cluster it should be something along this lines:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -printTopology
Rack: /default-rack
   172.31.xx.xx:50010 (ip-172-31-xx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.internal)
   172.31.xx.xx:50010 (ip-172-31-xx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.internal)
```

And the same should be seen in executors' address in the UI (by default it's http://your-cluster-public-dns:8080/).

In my case I was using public hostname for spark slaves. I have changed my `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` in `$SPARK/conf/spark-env.sh` to use the private name as well, and after that change I get `NODE_LOCAL` most of the times.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your answer clearly. Where should I modify? Can you please give an example? Thanks.

Comment: Can you add output of `hdfs dfsadmin -printTopology`?

Comment: OK, I post it in the question.

Comment: @XingjunWang and the overview page of your cluster? Basically in my case the thing that you have in parenthesis (vm1-vm16 in your case) should be the same as the one spark sees. So you should check your hostname, and the `conf/spark-env.sh` config, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same problem today. This is my situation:

My cluster have 9 workers(each setup one executor by default) ,when i set `--total-executor-cores  9`, the Locality lever is NODE_LOCAL, but when i set the total-executor-cores below 9 such as `--total-executor-cores  7`, then Locality lever become ANY, and the total time cost is 10X than NODE_LOCAL lever.  You can have a try.

Comment: well, i found another ways to deal with it . you can try to increase spark conf spark.locality.wait to a larger number such as 50, or try to increase spark.locality.wait.process to 30, then you may get your result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running my cluster on EC2s, and I fixed my problem by adding the following to `spark-env.sh` on the name node

```
SPARK_MASTER_HOST=<name node hostname>
```

and then adding the following to `spark-env.sh` on the data nodes

```
SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME=<data node hostname>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't start slaves like this `start-all.sh`. u should start every slave alonely

```
$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-slave.sh -h <hostname> <masterURI>
```