# What is the difference between spark.task.cpus and --executor-cores

Tags: multithreading, apache-spark

In my mapPartition part, there are multi-threading works to do, I use thread pool and want to run a task in parallel. But I cannot distinguish these two parameters.
I guess I can set **--executor-cores** to 5, and I run 4 threads in my task. Is this right?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`spark.task.cpus` is the number of cores to allocate for each task and `--executor-cores` specify Number of cores per executor.

There is small difference between executor and tasks as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25286412/2784721).

For knowing how many threads you can run per core go through [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/668538/cores-vs-threads-how-many-threads-should-i-run-on-this-machine) post.

As per the links :

When you create the SparkContext, each worker starts an executor. This is a separate process (JVM). The executors connect back to your driver program. Now the driver can send them commands, like flatMap, map and reduceByKey, these commands are tasks.

For knowing number of threads your cpu supports per core run `lscpu`
and check value of `Thread(s) per core:`.

Comment: I set **spark.task.cpus**, **--executor-cores**, **--num-executors**, and I expect to get  **--executor-cores** *  **--num-executors** cores. But the cluster information shows I am wrong.

Comment: How are you getting cluster information? Are you getting confused with SPARK_WORKER_CORES and SPARK_EXECUTOR_CORES?

Comment: What is the cli argument for `spark.task.cpus`?