# Creating spark tasks from within tasks (map functions) on the same application

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, task, distributed-computing, bigdata

Is it possible to do a map from a mapper function (i.e from tasks) in pyspark?
In other words, is it possible to open "sub tasks" from a task?
If so - how do i pass the sparkContext to the tasks - just as a variable?

I would like to have a job that is composed from many tasks - each of these tasks should create many tasks as well, without going back to the driver.

My use case is like this:
I am doing a code porting of an application that was written using work queues -  to pyspark.
In my old application tasks created other tasks - and we used this functionality. I don't want to redesign the whole code because of the move to spark (especially because i will have to make sure that both platform works in the transient phase between the systems)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to open "sub tasks" from a task?

**No**, at least not in a healthy manner<sup>*</sup>.

A ***task*** is a command sent from the driver and Spark has as ***one Driver*** (central coordinator) that communicates with many distributed workers (executors).

As a result, what you ask for here, implies that every task can play the role of a sub-Driver. Not even a worker, which would have the same faith in my answer as the task.

Remarkable resources:

1. [What is a task in Spark? How does the Spark worker execute the jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276409/what-is-a-task-in-spark-how-does-the-spark-worker-execute-the-jar-file)
2. [What are workers, executors, cores in Spark Standalone cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621990/what-are-workers-executors-cores-in-spark-standalone-cluster)

---

*<sub>With that said, I mean that I am not aware of any hack or something, which if exists would be too specific.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the help - i thought that would be the answer.
I played a bit and I actually successfully created other applications (spark contexts) from tasks and things seemed to work fine on small scale cluster .
I was afraid that this is a hack and the behavior will be undefined...
You solved my dilema.

Comment: yes - and it worked - i had some problem in resource allocation since the main driver took all the cpu and the subtask's drivers got starved - but it can be solved using special and complex configurations....
I was afraid that this is too hacky, and that the behavior is undefined.

I also wanted to avoid the ugly configuration necessary - this is why i asked about sub tasks of the same application (my idea was to use fair scheduling to avoid the starvation).

Comment: @OferE. I understand you, hmm, if I was you, I would give it a shot with more machines, *but* on the same time modify my code to work as a nice, healthy Spark job. I mean haven't heard anybody doing what you are trying to do.. :)

Comment: since the driver is also thread safe - i thought that the tasks can open a communication channel to it - and submit the work to the driver - and use fair scheduling - but this is just too much....
I am doomed :-)

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking @OferE., I mean I haven't anybody talking about this, so I am not 100% sure that it cannot be done. However, if you wish to go for it, then you probably have a hard time. The approach in your last comment seems reasonable, but yes this might be too much..Good luck! ;)